# How to concat date string to another string using '=>'

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

```
string1 = "Incident is created";
string2 = "2020-08-01T02:00:45.000Z"
```

I want to concat both the strings so that final output looks as below:

`2020-08-01=>Incident is created`

I am doing `string1.concat(string2)` but it is not giving the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply and the **easiest** way is to use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let string1 = "Incident is created";
let string2 = "2020-08-01T02:00:45.000Z"
let string3 = '=>'

let concat = string2.split('T')[0].concat(string3, string1);

console.log(concat) //2020-08-01=>Incident is created
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()`

```js
string1 = "Incident is created";
string2 = "2020-08-01T02:00:45.000Z"

res = string2.split("T")[0]+"=>"+string1
console.log(res)
```